# Is there a way to repeat certain quests?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I liked a particular sequence in the The Black Star quest, even though it wasn't conducive to my character's skill-set. I think that I found a way to end it earlier than normal, so I'm curious if there was more to it.

Other than starting a new game or loading an old save, is there a way to repeat it and any quest in general?

Comment: Are you playing on the PC and, if so, would using console commands be acceptable?

Comment: Yes, I play on PC. Console commands are acceptable but discouraged.

Comment: @Studoku whether the OP is playing on PC is not is irrelevant, answers should be useful to everybody, not just the OP.

Comment: @kotekzot Which would invalidate any answer involving console commands, mods or save editing for any multi-platform game. Are you really telling me that's our policy now?

Comment: @Studoku no, I'm saying you should address all platforms and reasonable inclinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no satisfactory way to replay quests other than playing a game where the quest has not been completed. You can try using the console command `resetquest`, but your experience will likely be degraded. You can also obviously repeat repeatable radiant quests, such as bounties given by stewards and barkeepers and other minor jobs.

Comment: Just because your system is nerfed doesn't mean the OP (who said he's using a PC) shouldn't have a PC-based answer.  The possibility exists for him.  You've misled him.